# Gnome-Tweaks "Gnome shell not running"

Tags: gnome

I have been trying since yesterday to run and install GNOME Tweaks
but it tells me it already exists. But shell not running:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-tweaks is already the newest version (3.34.0-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

When I try to open it manually I am not able to find it.

So I try opening using terminal and this is what happens:

```
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 217, in __init__
    raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available

(gnome-tweaks:6503): dconf-WARNING **: 21:13:11.452: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(gnome-tweaks:6503): dconf-WARNING **: 21:13:11.453: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/app.py", line 30, in do_activate
    self.win = Window(self, model)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 58, in __init__
    self._model.load_tweaks(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakmodel.py", line 107, in load_tweaks
    mods = __import__("gtweak.tweaks", globals(), locals(), tweak_files, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_general.py", line 55, in <module>
    IgnoreLidSwitchTweak(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_general.py", line 28, in __init__
    GetterSetterSwitchTweak.__init__(self, _("Suspend when laptop lid is closed"), **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/widgets.py", line 469, in __init__
    sw.set_active(self.get_active())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_general.py", line 31, in get_active
    return not self._sync_inhibitor()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_general.py", line 42, in _sync_inhibitor
    bus = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SESSION, None)
gi.repository.GLib.Error: g-io-error-quark: The connection is closed (18)
```

Answer (score -1):

Download This:

http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/g/gnome-tweak-tool/gnome-tweak-tool_3.18.1-1_all.deb

Then:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Then Try to install it using `Gdebi`:

```
sudo gdebi gnome-tweak-tool_3.18.1-1_all.deb
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by simply removing `gnome-tweaks` then reinstalling it again:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-tweaks 
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```